Get drive's path using its name
I have a USB drive which letter/path could differ, but its name never changes.
I would like to find the path/letter of this drive, by looking up its name.
Is there a cmd command which could do this for me?
I've been searching for a good while and can't come up with a good solution.
Right now I have:
wmic path CIM_LogicalDevice where "Name like 'driveName'" get name

which confirms for me that the specific drive is indeed plugged in, but how would I go about finding its letter now?
I found it can be done using this PowerShell command:
Get-WMIObject Win32_Volume | ? { $_.Label -eq 'driveName' }

But I can't use PowerShell in my case...

Run a powershell command in cmd like this:
powershell -command "Get-WMIObject Win32_Volume | ? { $_.Label -eq 'driveName' }"

Yes, it's me answering my own question.

Answering your own Q is perfectly fine, encouraged even. No reason not to. Glad you figured it out.

Please have a look at Can I answer my own question? and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Not sure if its me, but in cmd i dont get anything ^^(gives all info on drive, you need letter(path)?). However, powershell -command "(Get-Volume | Where-Object { $_.FileSystemLabel -eq 'Win7Boot' }).DriveLetter + ':'" ,does ;)

Well, for me it gives me loads of info, among which is this:
...
"Caption                      : D:"
...
"DriveLetter                  : D:". But your command is better as I won't have to add a function to split and search the output string :D Thanks :)

Be careful with that, because if you query the wrong label accidentally, it'll return ":", but no drive letter, which could backfire if you pipe it directly to another command.

Ha! Thanks :) I accounted for that in my program already :)

You need to loop trough your drives;
-One line cmd;
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %D in ('wmic volume where "Label='Win7Boot'" get DriveLetter /value') do start %D:\
-save as bat file
@echo off
set "usbName=Win7Boot"

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%D in ('wmic volume where "Label='%usbName%'" get DriveLetter /value') do (
    start explorer %%D:\
    exit /b
)

echo USB drive with label "%usbName%" not found.
pause

-PowerShell from cmd

powershell -command "(Get-Volume | Where-Object { $_.FileSystemLabel -eq 'Win7Boot' }).DriveLetter + ':\'"


Thank you, I tried this and it worked! It's simpler to use [powershell - command ""] in cmd though!

Upvoted for pure DOS.


An alternative approach with a single loop could be:

@echo off

set "_VolumeName=BOOTDISK" && for /f usebackq^ ^Tokens^=^4^ ^Delims^=^<^> %%i in (` 
     wmic LogicalDisk where "DriveType=2 and VolumeName='%%_VolumeName%%'" get DeviceID^,VolumeSerialNumber /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
    `) do echo/"%%~i"| >nul find ":" && set "_DeviceID=%%~i" || set "_VolumeSerialNumber=%%~i"

set _ | findstr "_Dev _Vol""


Output:

_DeviceID=D:
_VolumeName=BOOTDISK
_VolumeSerialNumber=9ED49E6A



A  different way to handle this, using a single loop, could be:

@echo off

set "_VolumeName=BOOTDISK"

%:^?
if not defined _Caption =;( set "_get=Get Caption" );= else if not defined _DeviceID =;( set "_get=Get DeviceID"
    );= else if not defined _VolumeSerialNumber =;( set "_get=Get VolumeSerialNumber" );= else set "_get=" && goto %:^!

for /f usebackq^ ^Tokens^=^4^ ^Delims^=^<^> %%i in =;(`
     call wmic LogicalDisk where "DriveType=2 and VolumeName='%%_VolumeName%%'" %%_get%% /format:xml ^| find "VALUE" 
    `);= do set "%_get:* =_%=%%~i" & goto %:^?

%:^!
echo/1st for loop output: 
for %%G in =;( 
     Caption,DeviceID,VolumeName,VolumeSerialNumber 
    );= do call echo/%%~G=%%_%%~G%%

echo/
echo/2nd for loop output: 
for /f tokens^=^1*^ ^ delims^=^= %%i in =;( 
    'set _ ^| findstr "Capti Devi Volume"'
    );= do echo/VariableName %%~i == %%~j


This way, you’re pulling more detailed info in one go, like the DriveID, VolumeName, VolumeSerialNumber, and other useful properties. By filtering with DriveType=2 (removable drives) and checking for VolumeName='BOOTDISK', you can easily target the specific USB drive you’re interested in, getting all the key details at once.

Output:

1st for loop output:
Caption=D:
DeviceID=D:
VolumeName=BOOTDISK
VolumeSerialNumber=9ED49E6A

2nd for loop output:
VariableName _Caption == D:
VariableName _DeviceID == D:
VariableName _VolumeName == BOOTDISK
VariableName _VolumeSerialNumber == 9ED49E6A



  

"I have a USB drive which letter/path could differ, but its name never changes".


The volume name will always remain the same, and since this is a USB device, the drive type will consistently be 2. Therefore, I suggest using DriveType=2 and VolumeName='BOOTDISK' as conditions to get the relevant output/value.

wmic LogicalDisk where "DriveType=2 and VolumeName='BOOTDISK'" get driveID

   
   
 Numeric value that corresponds to the
     type of disk drive this logical disk represents. 





Name
Value
Description




Unknown
0
The type of drive is unknown.


NoRootDirectory
1
The drive does not have a root directory.


Removable
2
The drive is a removable storage device, such as a USB flash drive.


Fixed
3
The drive is a fixed disk.


Network
4
The drive is a network drive.


CDRom
5
The drive is an optical disc device, such as a CD or DVD-ROM.


Ram
6
The drive is a RAM disk.




 


Additional resources:

Set /?

Call /? 

For /?

For /F /?

Where /?

Findstr /?

Goto :Label /?

If() Else If() Else() /?

Conditional Execution

|| and &&


Commands Redirection

|, <, >, 2>, etc.

Set "_var=%_var:To=Substrings% in batch



Great information, thank you for taking the time!

Thank you for your comment, but please note that it’s simply the result of free time when available. d:)
